# Storing variable reference in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to save one variable as member of the object and than modify the reference to this variable. Is it possible in C#?

It's something like this:

```
class Foo
{
    int i;

    public Foo(ref int i) { this.i = i; }
    public void Bar(int i) { this.i += i; }
}

class Demo
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 10;

        Console.WriteLine(x);    // x = 10

        Foo foo = new Foo(ref x);
        foo.Bar(15);

        Console.WriteLine(x);    // x = 25
    }
}
```

So is there a way how to achieve this in C# for example with lambdas? Or is it impossible to do it without unsafe code?

Comment: No, this isn't possible. Rather than jumping though hoops to make this happen, why not just refer to `foo.i` (or a property that encapsulates it), instead of the local variable `x`?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120789/c-sharp-passing-parameters-by-reference-to-constructor-then-using-them-from-me

Comment: @spender foo.Bar should be called from another function and the i member should have another type (if we use generics)

Comment: You can obviously wrap access to delegates...

Comment: @dustmouse yes this is one solution however when this would be class for an user and he want to use normal int he must create new specialized wrapper.

Comment: _"he must create new specialized wrapper"_ -- be that as it may, that's how it's accomplished in C#. The marked duplicate answers precisely the question you've asked. If you have some specific constraints that you haven't shared here, you could post a new question describing those constraints, providing a good [mcve] showing what you've tried with respect to dealing with those constraints. At the end of the day though, you're going to have to wrap access to the field in _something_.