# (Nested) ViewModel for primitive (value) datatypes (numbers, enums)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a wpf application. I use the mvvm pattern.
I have several usercontrols and I want them to have their own viewmodels because I want to reuse these usercontrols in different views without implementing the same (uc-specific) logic in a "super"-viewmodel again and again.

So I have different main viewmodels for every view and each of these viewmodels creates an instance of my subviewmodel, passing a certain property of my model in the constructor of the subviewmodel.

As long as this property is a reference type (class, List<>,...), the changes I make in the subviewmodel/usercontrol are made directly to the model itsself (since it's a reference type). 
But when the subviewmodel is for a primitive type, like an integer or an enum, this does not happen because the value is only a copy of the value an when I edit this value I edit the copy and not the value of the model, of course.

How can I solve this? What can I do to get the changed value back to my model?

I do not want to implement a "viewmodel-communication-service" because this seems to be too "big" for the small app I'm working on. For the same reason I also don't want to use any  third party components.

In the main viewmodel, should I listen to the propertychanged event of the subviewmodel (and check if the changed property is my primitive property (check its name) and write the new value back to the model)? Hmm that should work but I'm no big fan of using events in scenarios like this since they arrive asynchronously.

Or is it possible to somehow pass the primitive type to the subviewmodel as a ref value (like using ref for method parameters)?

Comment: This might be as simple as just passing in the value **by reference** into the constructor: `public MyViewModel(ref int something)`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx).

Comment: Or use `Int32` instead of `int`.

Comment: @MikeEason, it is possible to create a construtor like this, but it is not possible to store the passed references as local variables in my class. See this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120789/c-sharp-passing-parameters-by-reference-to-constructor-then-using-them-from-me.