# Reference to var c#

Tags: c#

I wonder if there is a way to use a reference of a var like 'ref' but not in a method.
exemple :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Class3
{
    struct myStruct
    {
        public bool structBool;
        public int structInt;
        public myStruct(bool _structBool, int _structInt)
        {
            structBool = _structBool;
            structInt = _structInt;
        }
    }
    myStruct currentTask;
    int value1,value2;
    bool mybool, isProcessing;
    Queue<myStruct> myTask = new Queue<myStruct>();

    void main()
    {
    //these two lines don't work due to the "ref" but I'm looking for something work like this
        if (value1 > value2) myTask.Enqueue(new myStruct(mybool,ref value1));
        if (value2 > value1) myTask.Enqueue(new myStruct(mybool,ref value2));
        MyFunction();
    }

    void MyFunction()
    {
        if (myTask.Count > 0)
        {
            if (!isProcessing)
            {
                currentTask = myTask.Dequeue();
                isProcessing = true;
            }
            else
            {
                currentTask.structInt++;  // here I need to catch my var (value1 or value2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to put the values into an array but I think it's a bad way. I tried lot of other stuff but nothing work properly.

Comment: I'm missing the point of your question. The constructor for `myStruct()` doesn't take a `ref` param, nor does it do anything that would necessitate making it a `ref` param (like assigning to it). Why do you want to pass it as a `ref`?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your problem instead of technical difficulties? Maybe there is a better way around?

Comment: Is this what you want? `int value1 = 2; var s = new myStruct(mybool,ref value1); s.structInt = 3; Console.WriteLine(value1); /* outputs 3 */` -- that is to say, are you looking for what C would call a pointer to an int?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. There's no `var` in your code anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the constructor to pass those parameters by reference like so:

`public myStruct(bool _structBool, ref int _structInt)`,

The problem is that invoking this line

`currentTask.structInt++;`

still wouldn't change the original variables (`value1`, `value2`). Check the solution in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13120988/775018

Comment: I check but don't understand how this thread can solve my problem.

Comment: Hi. The proposed solution is the same as @matías-fidemraizer suggested. The idea is to wrap an integer into another class so that both `myStruct` and `MyFunction` could reference the same instance. So if you look at Matias' code: you can just change ` int value1,value2;` to 
`Args args1 = new Args();
Args args2 = new Args();`
and `public int structInt;` to `public Args structArgs` (change the constructor as well) and then just increment it like so: `currentTask.structArgs.Value++;`

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you want to give multiple values to a constructor (or even a method), it's very acceptable that you give them as part of a class:

```
public class Args
{
     public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

So now you can do this:

```
Args args1 = new Args { Value = 10 };
Args args2 = new Args { Value = 34 };

// Obviously, your structs or classes should accept Args class as input parameter
var struct1 = new MyStruct(true, args1);
var struct2 = new MyStruct(false, args2);
```

Now modifications to `Args.Value1` and/or `Args.Value2` will be available for the struct constructor callers.