# Easy way to share private variables with constructed class in C#

Tags: c#

So I'm aware of several ways to make private fields accessible to other classes, I just I feel like their must be an easier way because I could do it easier in C++ with pointers.

Basically, I have a class with a large number of integers, that then creates a number of classes that use these integers. But each class only uses a few integers each. What I want is to allow each class to access only the variables that they need, but have all the remaining integers be unaccessible.

Basically what I would do in C++ is:

```
class PrivateClass
{
private:
    int a, b, c, d;
public:
    void DoStuff();
};
```

And then

```
void DoStuff()
{
    ClassOne class_one(&a, &b);
    ClassTwo class_two(&c, &d);
    //stuff
}
```

So then *class_one* has access to the values of *a* and *b*, while *class_two* has access to the values of *c* and *d*. (Also, if I've made any errors in my code forgive me, it has been a while since I've actually written in C++)

Given how easy it is to do there, it makes me feel (perhaps erroneously) like there must be a similarly easy method in C#. If not, I'll mostly just make an indexer to encapsulate the variables so that they can be accessed that way.

Edit: Basically I'm getting that I should just use properties like I've been weirdly avoiding. I don't mind making properties for a few fields, but for some reason doing it for 30 or so just feels wrong, like there should be a better way.

Comment: Variables only exist inside a method. They can't be shared. You're confusing them with fields perhaps *which aren't meant to be shared among objects*. Fields are *implementation details*. Use properties instead. These aren't fancy getter/setter methods. Properties are actually part of a type's API, expected to remain unchanged, automatically serialized by all serializers, bound to UI elements through data binding, validated through validators, etc. Fields aren't used in any of these cases and are expected to change whenever the developer wants to

Comment: _"Given how easy it is to do there"_ if something can be "easily" done does not mean that it should be done.

Comment: I don't see your problem. Is the question about accessing a private member from **another class** or from the **same**. Your `DoStuff`-function within the C++-code also lives in the same class, that's why it works there. Doing `&a` from within **another** class won't compile in neither C# nor in C++.

Comment: It is filed (private member of a class) for a reason. You can still use unsafe code blocks to use pointers or make a wrapper to wrap your integers like shown in this question;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120789/c-sharp-passing-parameters-by-reference-to-constructor-then-using-them-from-me

But you shouldn't be doing neither of these. You can use properties instead.

Comment: If you find yourself accessing private fields from the outside, you have a huge design-issue. You should make those members public (preferably public properties).

Comment: `Given how easy it is to do there,` that's actually a very bad idea in C++ and extremely error prone. It also contradicts your entire question - if `ClassOne` only needed access to its own fields, it wouldn't need to read them from the outside. This means something else is modifying those values already

Comment: Is this an attempt to create a "function object" in C++? That's not how they work

Comment: Probably what you *should* be doing, is moving some of the code that accesses those fields into the class, and therefore the fields remain private

Comment: What is your use case?  There's probably a clean C# way to do what you want (but we can't tell from your example).  Don't forget that integers are value types, most of what you want to do with value type instances is work with the values.  There's are big differences between "an object", "a value" and "a variable" (and for that matter "fields", "properties" and "variables").

Comment: The way to approach this depends a lot on what you mean by "a large number of integers." Does that mean five? Ten? Potentially 1,000? Is it undetermined? I have some ideas but I can't guess which one makes sense without understanding the problem.

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos You're right. I shouldn't be asking questions when I'm sleep deprived. Since I deal heavily in mathematics my brain always wants to call everything a variable, when that isn't what it is here. Basically I'm trying not to write properties for all 30 or so fields I'm using.  For some reason that just looks wrong to me, but that's most likely just an issue I have. But I figured that was most likely what I was going to end up doing, I just wanted to see if there was an alternative that I was just unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of sharing private variables with another class doesn't quite make sense. There are various access modifiers, but that doesn't help if you want one class to have access to certain members, another class to have access to different members, and so forth.

So the first question is how to share variables. Typically we do that with properties.

In this example another class can read `A` but can't change it. Another class can both read and write `B`. There is no property for changing `_c`.
If we want to split hairs, nothing outside the class can actually read or change the variables. They can only access the property, and the property reads/writes the variable.
(You can also do this with auto-properties. You don't need a variable and a separate property. But that's irrelevant for now.)

```cs
class PrivateClass
{
    private int _a;
    private int _b;
    private int _c;

    public int A => _a;
    public int B
    {
        get { return _b; }
        set { _b = value; }
    }
};
```

Next you want to be able to control which classes can "see" which variables.
As long as there are properties, you can't absolutely prevent someone from writing code that calls them. But you can control how one class "sees" another class.

Here's a contrived example. These types don't make much sense.

```cs
public class PublicTransportVehicle : IPublicTransport, IMotorVehicle
{
    public int PassengerCapacity { get; private set; }
    public int PassengerCount { get; set; }
    public int AxleCount { get; private set; }
}

public interface IPublicTransport
{
    int PassengerCapacity { get; }
    int PassengerCount { get; set; }
}

public interface IMotorVehicle
{
    int AxleCount { get; }
}
```

The `PublicTransportVehicle` class has three `int` properties. Two are read-only. One is read-write. (I used auto-properties instead of variables. This just means that if `set` is private then only the class itself can set the property.)

Now I can write a class with a method that takes an argument of type `IPublicTransport`. I can pass an instance of `PublicTransportVehicle` or any other class that implements the interface. But the method only sees `IPublicTransport`. The only properties it knows about are the ones exposed by that interface.

I can write another method that takes an argument of type `IMotorVehicle` and it only interacts with the properties defined in that interface.

I can pass an instance of `PublicTransportVehicle` to either method because it implements both interfaces, but each one sees it differently.

---

Can we absolutely prevent the caller from accessing properties we didn't want it to access? That's a lot harder. For example, a class could do this:

```cs
public void DoSomethingWithMotorVehicle(IMotorVehicle motorVehicle)
{
    var publicTransportVehicle = motorVehicle as PublicTransportVehicle;
    if (publicTransportVehicle != null)
    {
        publicTransportVehicle.PassengerCount = 1000;
    }
}
```

But we usually can't and shouldn't bother trying to exercise complete control over that. It's practically impossible. The idea is to communicate which properties and methods consumers are expected to interact with. We do that by deliberately making them accessible. If someone wants to something weird like casting an object or using reflection there's not a lot we can do. Unless it's a serious security-related matter we don't need to worry about that.

Comment: Hit it on the head with "Sharing private variables doesn't make much sense". If you want a variable to be accessible outside of the class, it shouldn't be private.

Comment: This basically does what I would want it to by only giving each class access to the properties it needs. Though I guess another question is - is it actually necessary? If I have 10+ classes/methods that each need access only to a few different properties, is it worthwhile to actually make different interfaces for each one?

I like this style better, but I think I might just be looking for a solution to a problem that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: I've spent lots of time looking for solutions to problems I didn't actually have. Breaking that habit was the best thing ever. If there's a single object with lots of properties and those properties make sense being in the same object, maybe it's okay for all the consumers to work with that object, use the properties they need, and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Make the method static and send the corresponding instance to it, then you can access the data you want.

```
Static Void DoStuff(PrivateClass instance)
{
    ClassOne class_one(instance.a, instance.b);
    ClassTwo class_two(instance.c, instance.d);
    //stuff
}
```

But the reality is that it is wrong, you should either add reading and writing properties to your variables to be able to send them to DoStuff from outside as a parameter.

```
//in Main
PrivateClass pClass = new PrivateClass(1,30,2,19);
DoStuff(pClass.A, pClass.B, pClass.C, pclass.D);

//in PrivateClass

namespace Test
{
    class PrivateClass
    {
        private int a;
        private int b;
        private int c;
        private int d;

        public PrivateClass(int a, int b, int c, int d)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
            this.d = d;
        }

        public int A
        {
            get
            {
                return this.a;
            }
            set
            {
                this.a = value;
            }
        }//etc
        
        public static void DoStuff(int a, int b, int c, int d)
        {
            ClassOne class_one(a, b);
            ClassTwo class_two(c, d);
            //stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're passing these `a, b, c, d` by values, while *Invidia* wants to pass them by reference: in your case, once DoStuff is called, `class_one` and `class_two` will receive initial values, and any updates to `PrivateClass`'s values won't translate to them

Answer (score 0):

Private fields, methods, properties, constructors, and events are all meant to be used **by the class only**. If you want to access these fields from other classes, you can make something like this:

```cs
using System;

namespace SharePrivateFields
{
    class Supervisor
    {
        void DoStuff()
        {
            var subject = new Subject();
            var first = new First(subject);
            var second = new Second(subject);
        }

    }

    class Subject : IFirstSubject, ISecondSubject
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }
        public int C { get; set; }
        public int D { get; set; }
    }

    interface IFirstSubject
    {
        int A { get; set; }
        int B { get; set; }
    }
    interface ISecondSubject
    {
        int C { get; set; }
        int D { get; set; }
    }

    class First
    {
        private IFirstSubject _subject;

        public First(IFirstSubject subject)
        {
            _subject = subject;
        }

        protected void DoMagic()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_subject.A); // Completely correct
            Console.WriteLine(_subject.C); // `IFirstSubject` does not contain definition for `C`
        }
    }

    class Second
    {
        private ISecondSubject _subject;

        public Second(ISecondSubject subject)
        {
            _subject = subject;
        }
        protected void DoMagic()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_subject.A); // `ISecondSubject` does not contain definition for `A`
            Console.WriteLine(_subject.C); // Completely correct
        }
    }
}
```

**However**, we're now treading waters of [Abstract Factory Design Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/abstract-factory), which is a more desirable approach in this case.
I'm convinced that the C++ implementation you're mentioning is a flawed design, so it's a reason why you can't make it easy in C# (if we're being completely honest - you can, read about [Unsafe code, pointer types, and function pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code); but it's 99% of a time taboo for C# code).

So I suggest you learn about Abstract Factory or at least use my solution for your use-case.